# How to rescue my fittonia from white mold?

Tags: houseplants, mold

[image]

I’m trying to rescue my sister’s fittonia. They were very dry when I got them but after repotting them, I notice this white moldy stuff on all the stems and the leaves were all wilting. Please help!